# PHP Dynamic method calling inquery

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

After creating my own MVC framework with very good timings in complex applications, i have a question.
I dynamically execute functions like this:

```
<?php
class dyn {
  public function do_me() {
    echo "hello";
  }
  public function execute_other_method($var = 0) {
    if ($var != 0 && method_exists($this, $var)) {
      $this->$var();
    }
  }
}

$do_method = "do_me"; // this variable is usually from GET or POST, it's dynamically set anyway
$class = new dyn;
$class->execute_other_method($do_method); // echoes hello
?>
```

This works flawlessly, but my question is: Does it have any downsides?

If i can improve this method of execution i would gladly do it.

Now i get 0.0080s ~ 0.0150s average and 0.0300s max in executing complex web pages on a local PC as server (web page includes db query, preg_match/replace, calculations etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you wouldn't use the __get method instead? It's designed to do exactly what you did above except that instead of calling execute_other_method, you would call

```
$class->do_me(); // this method exists and __get will call the method for you.
```

or

```
$class->other_method(); // this method doesn't exist, but __get can handle it without throwing an error.
```

Then you won't have to pass your method name into another method.

Comment: execute_other_method is not a dedicated function to execute other function in my real app, inside it there are a few other things that have to be executed right before the execution of the method, for example checks if user is logged in or if methods are protected from dynamic calling (custom protection, i had to fool proof it).

Comment: Basicalli it's like this:
function execute($code) {
  if (is_allowed($code) && is_custom($code) && !is_protected($code)){
    $this->$code();
  }
}

Comment: You can still do that with the __get method.
see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php
for more details. It's just there to make calling methods easier and more direct.